# Nginx reverse proxy configurations for Wordpress Multisite using WP Super Cache

Tags: apache, caching, nginx, wordpress

I'm trying to setup nginx as a reverse proxy, for serving static files, in front of apache. I'm having trouble configuring nginx for a Wordpress Multisite, using WP Super Cache. I have the following configuration, which doesn't work:

```
server {
listen 80;

# Main site domain
server_name main.com *.main.com;

# Mapped domains
server_name mapped.com www.mapped.com;

root /home/me/www/wordpress/htdocs;
access_log /home/me/www/wordpress/logs/access.log;
error_log /home/me/www/wordpress/logs/error.log;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

error_page 404 = @wordpress;
log_not_found off;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 24h;
    log_not_found off;
}

############## WP MULTISITE ############## 

rewrite ^/files/(.+) /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;

location ^~ /files/ {
    rewrite ^.*/files/(.+)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
}

# Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}

############## WP MULTISITE ##############

############## WP SUPER CACHE ############

if (-f $request_filename) {
     #expires max;
     break;
  }
  if (-d $request_filename) {
     break;
  }
  set $supercache_file '';
  set $supercache_uri $request_uri;

  if ($request_method = POST) {
     set $supercache_uri '';
  }
  if ($query_string) {
     set $supercache_uri '';
  }

  if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author_|wordpress|wp-postpass_" ) {
     set $supercache_uri '';
  }

  if ($supercache_uri ~ ^(.+)$) {
     set $supercache_file /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$1index.html;
  }

  if (-f $document_root$supercache_file) {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ $supercache_file break;
  }

############## WP SUPER CACHE ############

location @wordpress {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @wordpress;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
}
```

I get the following errors, when loading pages:

```
main.com : 310 - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
main.com/wp-admin/ : Loads WP admin page
www.main.com : Welcome to nginx!
mapped.com / www.mapped.com: 403 - Forbidden - "You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server."
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit functions.php in your theme directory.

Add these code:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

OR

install this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/

Comment: I decided to get rid of Apache all together, and now I'm running Wordpress using only Nginx - haven't looked back since. You answer does seem to be a solution to my problem, so I'm gonna go ahead and accept it. I'm sorry for the late reply.